# data type conversion in DolphinDB

Tags: type-conversion, dolphindb

I was trying to convert the elements of a vector to different data types and got the following error message. I am wondering if there is a way to perform this type of data type conversion.

```
a = ["1", "2", "3"]
b = [INT, INT, LONG]
c = a $ b

c = a $ b => A scalar object is expected. But the actual object is a vector.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the higher-order function `loop`:

```
a = ["1", "2", "3"]
b = [INT, INT, LONG]
c = loop($, a, b)
c;

(1,2,3)

typestr c[0];

INT

typestr c[2];

LONG
```